# Do "Ku" or "Klux" have any historical meaning beyond being associated with the Klan?

Tags: etymology, american-english, history

I would like to know about how the name of this group was formed. According to [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=ku%20klux%20klan) the terms Ku Kux have a Greek origin, but it does not give  more information:

> - 1867, American English, ***originally Kuklux Klan*** , a made-up name, supposedly ***from Greek kuklos, kyklos "circle"***.

Can anyone provide  more information about the origin of the terms "Ku Klux" and how they came to be associated with  the well-know Klan?

Comment: I thought I knew the answer to this question, but a little checking of "commonly-available references" come with enough differing suggestions to suggest that this question might be legitimately considered an open question.

Answer (score 11):

***Early news reports about the organization***

In support of the "by 1867" origin of the secret society, here are two mentions of "Kuklux Klan" from the *Pulaski [Tennessee] Citizen*, published in that year. First from the [*Pulaski [Tennessee] Citizen*](http://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn85033964/1867-03-29/ed-1/seq-3/#words=%22kuklux%22) (March 29, 1867):

> WHAT DOES IT MEAN?—The following mysterious "Take Notice" was found under our door early yesterday morning, having doubtless been slipped there the night previous. Will any one venture to tell us what it means, if it means anything at all? What is a "**Kuklux Klan**," and who is this "Grand Cyclops" that issues his mysterious and imperative orders? Can any one give us a little light on this subject? Here is the order:
>
> "TAKE NOTICE.—The **Kuklux Klan** will assemble at their usual place of rendezvous, The Den," on Tuesday night next, exactly at the hour of midnight in costume and bearing the arms of the Klan.
>
> By or of the Grand Cyclops.
>
> G.T.".

And then from "[Kuklux Klan](http://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn85033964/1867-04-05/ed-1/seq-3/#words=%22kuklux%22)," in the *Pulaski [Tennessee] Citizen* (April 5, 1867):

> Another one of those mysterious communications from the Grand Cyclops of the **Kuklux Klan** found its way under our door yesterday morning, left there  we suppose by the Grand Turk. We are warned not to make an effort to find out objects of the "mystic klan," and to allow the Grand Cyclops to issue his orders without molestation. Well, old Cyclops, just issue as many orders as you please, but if we catch your Grand Turk "cyphering" round our door late at night, we'll upset him with a "shooting-stick." Look out, old Turk, we are some Cyclops ourself on our own premises. But we give our readers the benefit of the communication:
>
> EDITOR OF CITIZEN:—You seem to express, in your last issue, some surprise and curiosity in regard to the **Kuklux Klan**, whose boldness and affrontery should so startle you. That they should dare send forth their imperial edicts; or that the GRAND CYCLOPS should presume to dispatch his Grand Turk with orders to his faithful followers, or that they should dare come so near your editorial sanctum, as to leave one of their orders under your door. ...
>
> But seek not to know the object and designs of the "Mystic Klan," or to impeach the authority of our GRAND CYCLOPS to issue his mandates, for your efforts will be fruitless. If you see proper to publish our orders and will do so, we thank you, but more of the "**Kuklux Klan**" you *cannot* know. By order of the Klan, G.S.

Subsequent articles about the Klan—often introducing further messages from the organization—appeared regularly at the *Pulaski Citizen* for many weeks thereafter, published on [April 12](http://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn85033964/1867-04-12/ed-1/seq-3/#words=%22kuklux%22), [April 19](http://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn85033964/1867-04-19/ed-1/seq-3/#words=%22kuklux%22) (featuring a visitation from a personage who "appeared to be about nine feet high, with a most hideous face, and wrapped in an elegant robe of black silk" and carried "a magic wand" in "gloves the color of blood"), [April 26](http://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn85033964/1867-04-26/ed-1/seq-3/#words=%22kuklux%22), [May 3](http://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn85033964/1867-05-03/ed-1/seq-3/#words=%22kuklux%22), [May 17](http://www.elephind.com/?a=p&p=redirect&vhttp=http%3a%2f%2fchroniclingamerica.loc.gov%2flccn%2fsn85033964%2f1867-05-17%2fed-1%2fseq-3%2f%2f%3bwords%3d%22kuklux%22&vsource=ChroniclingAmerica) (a brief notice complaining that the editor had not heard from or been visited by a Klan representative in two weeks), [June 7](http://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn85033964/1867-06-07/ed-1/seq-3/#words=%22kuklux%22) (account of a midnight procession), [June 14](http://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn85033964/1867-06-14/ed-1/seq-3/#words=%22kuklux%22) (first quasi-political statement from the Klan, hinging on a joke about political versus gastrointestinal irregularity), and so forth.

The [June 21, 1867, installment](http://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn85033964/1867-06-21/ed-1/seq-3/#words=%22kuklux%22) juxtaposes a fairly innocuous note that "Alla Hassan, having been found guilty of a gross violation of the rules of the 'Klan' and the orders of the Grand Cyclops, and appearing in his august presence in a somewhat intoxicated condition, is forever expelled from the "Klan," and deprived of all its benefits and privileges," with a longer story headed "A Diabolical Lie" reporting that unnamed complainants were reporting to "the Bureau authorities" (presumably the local branch of the federal Freedmen's Bureau) on various outrages against freedmen in Giles county, including a lynching and various assaults committed by "a [white] mob" and by a "[white] party of roughs." The newspaper asserts that the complaints—variously "diabolical lies" and "atrocious lies"—were politically motivated and utterly false. So the *Pulaski Citizen*'s editorial outlook is clearly strongly anti-Reconstruction (as was the Klan's, when it emerged as a powerful political force in the U.S. South).

The earliest news report from a paper other than the *Pulaski Citizen* to mention the Kuklux Klan is in a [letter to the editor](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn85038521/1867-09-04/ed-1/seq-1/#words=%22kuklux%22) of the *Nashville [Tennessee] Union and Dispatch* (September 4, 1867) from an anonymous writer in Pulaski:

> Will you allow me a space in your columns for the purpose of refuting a base falsehood which appeared in that abominable sheet, the *Press and Times*, of the 29th ult., in the shape of a communication, purporting to be from a Union man of this place, representing the sentiment of this community as being outrageously disloyal ; that the lives of Union men were in imminent danger ; that there is in existence a secret organization here, having for its object the proscription of Union men and an assault on Brownlow's militia, and urging the necessity of an additional military force at this point to kep the turbulent Rebel element in subjection? ... The loyal man (so-called) is as safe from harm here as the one who ardently supported the Rebel cause. It is true there exists a secret organization here, "**Kuklux**," but having no such object as that mentioned in the *Press and Times*—on the contrary they have conducted themselves in a remarkable quiet manner, molesting no one—and have never evinced the least design of violence. But the guilty Rad,when he sees the mystic "**klan**," trembles and quakes with as much terror as did Belshazar while holding high carnival and indulging in bacchanalian revelry, he saw the hand writing on the wall and knew that the Medes and Persians were thundering at the gate of his palace. But they need not fear, as it is not t all probable that the "**Ku's**" will descend form their manly dignity, and, by an encounter, place themselves upon a level with such degraded specimens of humanity.

Pulaski is about 74 miles south of Nashville, near the border with Alabama. Presumably, the author of the above letter addressed it to the *Union and Dispatch* because he considered that newspaper sympathetic to the former Confederacy and, therefore, likely to publish his message.

---

***The source of the name***

The newspaper shows no interest in the meaning or etymology of the name *kuklux klan*, and very little journalistic curiosity as to the group's motives or intentions. In fact, the ornate, rather overblown letters from the Grand Cyclops quoted in the newspaper read very much like the work of a typical mid-nineteenth-century newspaper editor.

It is not impossible that the name has some dread and occult significance, but I incline to the theory that *kuklux* is nothing more than an alliterative nonsense word preceding the operative word *klan*. However, I would be remiss not to note that the Greek word Κυκλωφ (*Kuklops*) might be pronounced by a Southerner speaking Greek as a third, fourth, or fifth language as something similar to "Kuklox"; the only thing giving a hint of plausibility to this idea is the fact that in Pulaski, Tennessee, the personage comparable to the later Grand Dragon or Grand Wizard of the organization was initially called the Grand Cyclops, implying perhaps the organization's all-seeing eye. Wikipedia has a lengthy article about the [Klan's titles and vocabulary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ku_Klux_Klan_titles_and_vocabulary).

Still, anyone attempting to interpret the meaning of *Kuklux* should bear in mind the strain of exotic Orientalism characteristic of the early Klan's early presentation of itself (black silk or crimson robes, titles such as *Grand Turk*, and individual names such as "Alla Hassan"), which might invite further objectively silly foreign-sounding word inventions of the Gilbert and Sullivan school.

Comment: Those quotes almost lead one to suspect that the Klan was an invention of the *Citizen*, to boost circulation.  It would be incredibly ironic if it arose from such a bogus origin.

Answer (score 4):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ku_Klux_Klan#cite_note-48) gives the following information:

> "Horn 1939, p. 11, states that Reed proposed *κύκλος (kyklos)* and
>   Kennedy added *clan.* Wade 1987, p. 33 says that Kennedy came up with
>   both words, but Crowe suggested transforming *κύκλος* into *kuklux.*"

"Reed" referst to Richard R. Reed, "Kennedy" to John B. Kennedy and "Crowe" to James R. Crowe. These are the sources cited:

> Horn, Stanley F. (1939). Invisible Empire: The Story of the Ku Klux
>   Klan, 1866–1871. Montclair, New Jersey: Patterson Smith Publishing
>   Corporation.
>
> Wade, Wyn Craig. The Fiery Cross: The Ku Klux Klan in America (Oxford
>   University Press, 1998)

The article also states:

> "The name is probably derived from the Greek word *kuklos (κύκλος)* which
>   means circle; the word had previously been used for other
>   fraternal organizations in the South such as Kuklos Adelphon."

And, in another paragraph:

> "The group was known for a short time as the 'Kuklux Clan'."

Based on the above, I think it is reasonable to believe that "Ku Klux" was originally one word, "Kuklux", and derives from the Greek word *kuklos (κύκλος)*. It will be interesting to see what other people find.

My two cents.

Answer (score 2):

To complement @Sven Yargs' excellent [answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/364532/49890):

TL;DR: The name appears to have originated as Kuklux (after kuklos = circle), later Kuklux Klan, then Ku-Klux Klan, and finally Ku Klux Klan. The  name first appears in the Pulaski, Tennessee, newspaper because that town is where the organization was started.

The August 24, 1901, [*Peninsula Enterprise*](https://newspaperarchive.com/richmond-daily-dispatch-jan-01-1868-p-5/), a newspaper from Accomac Court House, Virginia, whose front page seems to be an agglomeration of news stories from other publications, contains a story titled "The Kuklux Klan: Where and How the Famous Body Was Organized," excerpted from *Atlantic Monthly*.

The same story also appears in the September 24, 1901, San Luis Obispo, California [*Morning Tribune*](https://cdnc.ucr.edu/?a=d&d=SLOMT19010924.2.14&e=-------en--20--1--txt-txIN--------1).

With this clue, I was able to find the original article in the [*Atlantic* archives](https://www.theatlantic.com/magazine/archive/1901/05/the-ku-klux-movement/544053/). The full article contains 7000 words, but the relevant part, which confirms that the origin of the organization and the name was Pulaski, Tennessee, is here:

> When the Civil War ended, the little town of Pulaski, Tennessee, welcomed home a band of young men who, though they were veterans of hard-fought fields, were for the most part no older than the mass of college students. In the general poverty, the exhaustion, the lack of heart, naturally prevalent throughout the beaten South, young men had more leisure than was good for them. A Southern country town, even in the halcyon days before the war, was not a particularly lively place; and Pulaski in 1866 was doubtless rather tame to fellows who had seen Pickett charge at Gettysburg or galloped over the country with Morgan and Wheeler. A group of them, assembled in a law office one evening in May, 1866, were discussing ways and means of having a livelier time. Some one suggested a club or society. An organization with no very definite aims was effected; and at a second meeting, a week later, names were proposed and discussed. Some one pronounced the Greek word “Kuklos,” meaning a circle. From “Kuklos” to “Ku Klux” was an easy transition, — whoever consults a glossary of college boys’ slang will not find it strange, — and “Klan” followed “Ku Klux” as naturally as “dumpty” follows “humpty.” That the name meant nothing whatever was a recommendation; and one can fancy what sort of badinage would have greeted a suggestion that in six years a committee of Congress would devote thirteen volumes to the history of the movement that began in a Pulaski law office, and migrated later to a deserted and half-ruined house on the outskirts of the village.

The *Atlantic* article goes on to explain how a club that was started as a lark, as "a scheme for having fun, more like a college secret society than anything else," turned into a terrorist organization.

(**Warning: Much of the material at the following link is offensive.** Consider the source.)

This origin story is corroborated by an article in the April, 1916, [*Confederate Veteran*](https://archive.org/details/confederateveter2419conf/page/156/mode/2up?q=kuklux+kuklos), the official publication of the United Daughters of the Confederacy, which claims:

> Pulaski, Giles County, Tenn., was the birthplace of the Ku-Klux Klan, which came into being and was perfected during the winter and spring of 1866. This town was noted for the culture and refinement of its people, a town of schools and colleges and churches, of the most elevating social, religious, and educational influences, and not a community that would likely produce cutthroats or desperadoes or engender an organization with low, ignoble, or evil purposes.

However, the *CV* continues by describing the white supremacist purposes that the Klan turned to:

> Amid these environments, all elevating and refining, the Ku-Klux Klan originated and was started on its great mission to protect the Southland, rescue it from its enemies, and place it on the highest plane of Caucasian civilization.

Even though:

> They first organized as a social club to hold meetings for recreation and social intercourse, to relieve the tedium and monotony following the stirring scenes and activities of war.

Regarding the name, the *CV* explains:

> The significant name "Ku-Klux” was really coined by the charter members. It was suggested that the Greek word “KuKlos,” meaning a circle, be given the organization. This finally was called “Ku-Klux,” and later Klan was added, making the three K's, or “Ku-Klux Klan,” which became so historic and significant.

The FBI's [KKK Monographs](https://archive.org/details/KKK-FBI-1958/fbi_kkk_1/page/n11/mode/2up) of 1958 reiterate the kuklos / circle / social club origin story but also acknowledge the Reconstruction Acts of 1867 as a major catalyst for the organization's change of mission.

An 1889 article in [*Gentleman's Magazine*](https://archive.org/details/gentlemansmagazi264unse/page/436/mode/2up?q=kuklos) also mentions the kuklos origin and identifies two distinct periods of its early existence, the first from May 1866 to summer 1867, and the second from summer 1867 to 1869.